# What does the equation $a^{-k} \pmod N$ or $a^{k+1} \pmod N$ do when $N$ is composite and $N = 4k+3$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was studying what the equation $a^{-k} \pmod p$ and $a^{k+1} \pmod p$ when $p$ is prime. It is not hard to show that both of those are square roots of $a$ in this special case.

In this special case (when $N = 3 \pmod 4)$, I was wondering what $a^{-k} \pmod p$ or $a^{k+1} \pmod p$ would do if $N$ was a composite made of two prime numbers. It is known that since $N$ is a composite made of distinct odd primes, that there are 4 square roots. Therefore, it occurred to me that $a^{-k}$ and $a^{k+1} \pmod p$ had to be one of the four square roots. However, I wasn't sure which ones of the square roots it returned (or which of the two pairs it returned. Notice we can always compute the other square root by $N-x$ since $-x \equiv N-x \pmod N$). Since, square roots always come in pairs since $x^2 \equiv (-x)^2 \pmod N$, I was wondering, which one of the four square roots does it return? Does $a^{-k}$ and $a^{k+1} \pmod p$ always guarantee to "hit" one of these two distinct pair (and hence yielding all four solutions) or do we have a 50/50 chance to hit both and hence get both square roots?

In other words, what is the relationship between $a^{k+1} \pmod p$ and $a^{-k}$? Is it true that $a^{k+1} \equiv - a^{-k} \pmod p$ (i.e. meaning we only ever get one of the two solutions?

Comment: Lots of things are confused about this question, but let's start with the basics when $N = 4k+3$ is prime. In this case, $a^{k+1}$ and $a^{-k}$ are both square roots of $a$ only when $a$ itself is a square. Moreover, when $a$ is square, then $a^{k+1} \equiv a^{-k} \mod p$. (The discussion when $N$ is composite is mostly bogus speculation which could be resolved by computing a single example.)